# Linq for taking values in variable through select query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sql-server-2005

By googling i have made following select query to take max value of column ID.

```
 var result = (from rs in db.tradeFiles

                             select (rs.ID)).Max();
```

Please let me know is this a query is write for taking max value of column ID.

And for taking data out of it in variables i used foreach loop in following manner which is also not working.

```
foreach(var item in result)
           {

           }
```

Please let me know what is the mistake and what is the correct way to pull out the data out of select query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Result is the value itself, just use it, there is no need to iterate over it. If for example `rs.ID` column is `int`, then result will be the `int`.

Comment: If var result = (from rs in db.tradeFiles

                             select (rs.ID)) this is the query, then how should i pull the individual ID value out of it?

Comment: @freelancer `from ... select` construct always return a list or results (IEnumerable to be exact). There are methods that can narrow down that list to 1 item, like `First` and `Single`.

Answer (score 1):

`Enumerable.Max` can't be enumerated, it returns the value you're looking for.

Comment: If var result = (from rs in db.tradeFiles select (rs.ID)) this is the query, then how should i pull the individual ID value out of it?

Answer (score 0):

in result you will get one int value.because you are taking max value of the column. it will give one single result.if you want to take some specific id value ,you just make one where condition and select that value.like

```
(from rs in db.tradeFiles
where rs.id==1
select (rs.Name)); something like this..
```